# Downloading Zip file From ZipOutPutStream using Jax-rs

Tags: java

I am creating one zip file using ByteArrayOutputStream and ZipOutPutSteam But its taking much delay for creating a big zip file near about 200mb. Is there any efficient way?

```
        URL u = new URL(url);
        URLConnection  uc = u.openConnection();

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream( out );
        zipOut.putNextEntry( new ZipEntry( "file.csv" ) );
        zipOut.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(uc.getInputStream()));
        uc.getInputStream().close();
        zipOut.closeEntry();
        zipOut.close();

        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(out.toByteArray());
        response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
        filename=\"LMPeriod.zip\"");
        return response.build();
```

Comment: You can try to play around with the compression level. You can pre compress the files. I.e. have some job that does the compression in the background. You may cache the zipped files. The compression itself still takes about 2microseconds for 1kB of data + reading data from the filesystem. With your solution (reading the whole file into memory and compress in memory) you may run into memory problems when having more much more than one concurrent download request.

Answer (score 0):

Use a FileOutputStream instead of ByteArrayOutputStream  to write the zip to disk.
The ByteArrayOutputStream caches the compressed result in memory. If you want it written to disk, you have to wrap the ZipOutputStream around a FileOutputStream.

Comment: And how does this solve the problem that zipping a file takes too long? Writing the file to disk is usually at least a factor 20 slower than memory access (memory 1microsecond, disk SSD 16 microseconds, compression 1kB about 2microseconds).